# Ansible cant install Microsoft Office 2016 in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, ansible, ms-office, silent-installer

```
    - name: Install | Install Microsoft Office 2016 | Mounting ISO
      community.windows.win_disk_image:
        image_path: C:\Temp\ansible_downloads\SW_DVD5_Office_2016_64Bit_Russian_MLF_X20-42506.ISO
        state: present
      register: mounted_iso
      changed_when: no

    - name: Install | Install Microsoft Office 2016 | Run installer from mounted ISO
      ansible.windows.win_package:
        path: '{{ mounted_iso.mount_paths[0] }}setup.exe'
        product_id: '{90160000-0012-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}'
        state: present
        arguments:
        - /adminfile C:\Temp\ansible_downloads\SW_DVD5_Office_2016_64Bit_Russian_MLF_X20-42506.MSP
```

```
PLAY [Install initial programs] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install | Install Microsoft Office 2016 | Mounting ISO] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [admin3]

TASK [Install | Install Microsoft Office 2016 | Run installer from mounted ISO] ********************************************************************************************************************************
```

And nothing happens. On the TASK [Install | Install Microsoft Office 2016 | Run installer from mounted ISO] stops any action. It probably has no end.

Difference when starting from powershell and from ansible in microsoft office install log:

Ansible:

```
2022/08/28 12:49:43:944::[13832] Command line: D:\setup.exe "/adminfile C:\Temp\ansible_downloads\SW_DVD5_Office_2016_64Bit_Russian_MLF_X20-42506.MSP"
2022/08/28 12:49:43:945::[13832] Parsing command line.
2022/08/28 12:49:43:945::[13832] Unrecognized command line parameter: /ADMINFILE C:\TEMP\ANSIBLE_DOWNLOADS\SW_DVD5_OFFICE_2016_64BIT_RUSSIAN_MLF_X20-42506.MSP
```

Powershell:

```
2022/08/28 12:38:09:012::[11908] Command line: D:\setup.exe  /adminfile C:\Temp\ansible_downloads\SW_DVD5_Office_2016_64Bit_Russian_MLF_X20-42506.MSP
2022/08/28 12:38:09:013::[11908] Parsing command line.
2022/08/28 12:38:09:013::[11908] Admin patch file/path specified: C:\Temp\ansible_downloads\SW_DVD5_Office_2016_64Bit_Russian_MLF_X20-42506.MSP
```

The problem is that the ansible passes the argument in quotes. Is it possible to remove these quotes?

Of course, there is an alternative, I can send win_shell with when product_id is not have condition, that will solve the problem. But perhaps there is a way to do this through win_package?

Comment: Did you try to separate each arguments on their own list items? (I.e separate the option and the filename that follows)

Comment: Please check the [examples in documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_package_module.html#examples). Either pass all as a single string or as a list with each element in its own item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the advice of [zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator), I split the argument into two arguments:

```
    - name: Install | Install Microsoft Office 2016 | Run installer from mounted ISO
      ansible.windows.win_package:
        path: '{{ mounted_iso.mount_paths[0] }}setup.exe'
        product_id: '{90160000-0012-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}'
        state: present
        arguments:
        - /adminfile
        - C:\Temp\ansible_downloads\SW_DVD5_Office_2016_64Bit_Russian_MLF_X20-42506.MSP
```

and it worked! Thanks!